# Exception behaving differently

Tags: c++, exception

I was playing around with C++ exceptions, but while writing a program I am not able to explain the output. So my understanding is whenever an exception is thrown the program looks for a matching try block, if there isnt one in the current scope all the stack variables will be destroyed and the caller will be searched for the try block, if a try is encountered a matching catch block is searched.Before moving to the matching catch all the stack variables inside the try block are destroyed. If one catch block is found the exception is handled and the program continues after the catch block. However in the following program I am not getting the output as expected:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Bomb { 
    int x;
    public:
        Bomb( ):x(0) {
            cout<< "callling constructor " << endl;
        }

        ~Bomb() {
           cout<<" Calling destructor " << endl;
           throw "boom";    
        }

        void * operator new( size_t size ) throw() {
            cout<<" Calling operator new " << endl;
            return malloc(size);
        }

        void  operator delete( void * p ) throw() {
            cout<<" Calling operator delete " << endl;
            if( p != 0 ) free(p);
        }
};

void f() {

    //Bomb myBomb;

    Bomb *pBomb = new Bomb();
    try {
        delete pBomb;
    } catch(  ... ) {
        cout<< " caught exception " << endl;
    }

}


int main( int argc, char ** argv ) {

    try {
        f();
    }
    catch(  char * message ) {
        cout << " caught exception in main " << endl;
    }
}
```

The output is:
   calling operator new
   calling constructor
   calling destructor
and then it crashes

I was expecting caught exception.

Am i missing something fundamental ?

Comment: What do you mean it crashes? I compiled your example, and it works as expected : `Calling operator new 
callling constructor 
 Calling destructor 
 caught exception`

Comment: Other than the problem described in the answers, "boom" isn´t a modifyable `char*`, but `const char*`

Comment: @deviantfan doesn't matter. That catch is never reached anyway

Comment: @BЈовић Please read more carefully. `Other than the problem described in the answers` ... if it matters in this specific example or not isn´t the problem, but it´s another error.

Comment: @deviantfan: the "modifyable `char*` vs. `const char *`" thing doesn't matter iiuc, see C++11 standard 5.17.2: `Evaluating a throw-expression with an operand throws an exception (15.1); the type of the exception object
is determined by removing any top-level cv-qualifiers from the static type of the operand and adjusting the
type from “array of T” or “function returning T” to “pointer to T” or “pointer to function returning T,”
respectively.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It matters a lot whether you are using C++11 or an earlier standard.

In an earlier standard, I *believe* that what you expected is what would have happened. However in C++11, destructors are implicitly given a `noexcept` specification unless you explicitly don't give them this, or unless they have a child member variable whose destructor is not marked `noexcept`... (reaches for standard...)

Comment: Ah yes, well-caught. If you add `throw (std::exception)` to the destructor then it behaves as expected. But if that's removed or changed to `throw()` then `std::terminate` is called because an unexpected exception was thrown.

Comment: @Claudiu Even if technically correct (not sure if it really is), don´t make a throwing destructor. Think about eg. what happens with automatic storage variables...

Comment: @deviantfan: I think the behavior is well-defined: if a destructor throws an exception and there's no current exception being propagated, then that destructor's exception propagates, but if there's already an exception propagating then `std::terminate` is called. But yes, definitely agree about not making a throwing destructor.

Comment: There is a really nice and exhaustive blog post on this topic here: https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2013/08/20/noexcept-destructors/

Comment: Actually this is the *really* exhaustive one of his on this topic: https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2011/09/21/destructors-that-throw/